# Pull JobTitle from Person field in JSLink

Tags: jslink, user-information-list

I'm using the following code in a webpart JSLink to pull user information from a Person and Groups Field:

```
    (function () {

    var overrideCtx = {};

    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

    overrideCtx.Templates.Item = itemOverrideFunc;

     overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;

    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
  })(); 

function itemOverrideFunc(ctx) 
{
 var users = ctx.CurrentItem["People"];

  for(i = 0; i < users.length; i++){

       var curUserName = users[i].title;

       // access department information of user or group
        var curUserDepartment = users[i].department;

        // access email address of user or group
        var curUserEmail = users[i].email;

       // access job title of user or group
       var curUserJobTitle = users[i].jobtitle;

       // access user picture url
       // contains the picture form the user profile service
       var curUserPicture = users[i].picture;

    }
 var ret = "<div class=\"divname1\" style=\"margin-bottom:20px;clear:both;\">"
    ret += "<div class=\"divname2\" style=\"float:left;width:90px\">"
    ret += "<img src=\"" + curUserPicture + "\"\>" + "</div>" 
    ret += "<div class=\"divname3\" style=\"float:left;width:500px;\">"
    ret += "<h2 style=\"margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px\">" + curUserName + "</h2><a href=\"mailto=" + curUserEmail + "\">" + curUserEmail +   "</a><br/>" + curUserJobTitle + "<br/>" + curUserDepartment + "<br/>" + ctx.CurrentItem.About_x0020_Me + ""
    ret += "</div><div style=\"clear:both\"></div>";
    ret += "</div>";

    return ret;

    }
```

Everything is working great except the curUserJobTitle which returns an "undefined" error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try users[i].title instead of jobtitle.

Comment: users[i].title actually returns the name of the person. I've updated my code above.

Comment: Good point, scratch that :)

Comment: Have you checked whether the "Title" field is filled out in the hidden users list? http://sharepoint/sitecollection/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx

Comment: Hi Erin, yes I have. There are three columns in my hidden User Information List. The Title column is filled out for the users. In my User Profiles in Central Administration there is actually a Title field and a Job Title field. I have tried many combinations of users[i].sps-jobtitle, users[i].ows_jobtitle etc with no luck.

Comment: The UIL actually doesn't have a photo, or email. So I'm curious, where is it actually pulling these two items from. That might help me find the job title.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. This was a problem of case. The correct line for Job Title is

```
var curUserJobTitle = users[i].jobTitle;
```

For those interested I found the correct property name by adding the following

```
var keyNames = Object.keys(users[i]);
for (b = 0; b < keyNames.length; b++) {
  console.log(keyNames[b]);
```

just under

```
for(i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
```